# How to break down expdp in into smaller pieces

Tags: oracle

I am new to Oracle 11g and need some help.  I have expdp that is almost 15G and I have to encrypt it.  My problem is that my encryption software only encrypts up to 2G. How do break down this 15G but expdp it all.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`FILESIZE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#autoId30) parameter, and make sure you either specify enough dump files, or use a `%U` flag on the dump file name (see [`DUMPFILE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#autoId22)).

e.g.:

```
expdp user/pass SCHEMAS=bob DIRECTORY=dumpdir DUMPFILE=export_%U.dmp FILESIZE=1G
```

Comment: Will have have to change anything when I import,since it will have multiply files.  Thanks again

Comment: Use the exact same name/syntax for the DUMPFILE parameter as you do for the export, and that's it, set all your other parameters as you did before. (You don't need to (and shouldn't) specify the FILESIZE parameter for import.)