# How to export an Oracle Table Chunk-wise to CSV?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, export-to-csv

I'm having a large Oracle table that has more than 10 million records. Due to download limitations, I need to export the oracle table by set by sets to CSV. Is there any way to download the table chunk-wise?
Note: I'm using Oracle 11g and Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: There is not enough information to help here: What Oracle client are you using? What language is the csv export implemented in? Why do you need to create chunks and can not just export row by row?

Comment: I'm using Oracle SQL Developer. It is Okay to export row by row, but the need to make sure only relevant set is extracted at a time.

Comment: If you are using the build-in export to csv in SQL Developer you should change the tasks ans ask accordingly. I'm pretty sure that SQL Developer has no build-in chunking when exporting. Does SQL Developer throw an error? The only way I can think of, would be to manually export batches of rows limited by "some" key.

Comment: Let sqldev generate the csv file. Once it's ready, use an OS shell script to split the file up in as many pieces as necessary.

Comment: Does [this(datapump exporting by pieces)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324342/how-to-break-down-expdp-in-into-smaller-pieces) answer your question ..?

Comment: Hi what is the row count limit for the row export to CSV ? Do you want to export all the 10 million rows but in chunks ? If the limit is 1 million, then you can write 10 SQL's and export to a csv. 
set linesize 2
set numwidth 5
spool File1.csv
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT * FROM   table order by primary_key ; 
) WHERE rownum > 1 and rownum < 1000000  -- For the 2nd query start with rownum > 999999 and < then 200000
spool off

Comment: @hkandpal Thank you. I used the same way you mentioned to filter out the rows by batch-wise.

Comment: @hkandpal `where rownum > any_number_greater_than_one` will not return anything, because `rownum` is a pseudocolumn generated at the output: you absolutely have to have `rownum = 1` in the result.

Comment: @astenx I've done few modifications to the code. `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT t.*, rownum rnum FROM table t order by primary_key ) WHERE rnum>= 1 
 and rnum < 1000000 -- For the 2nd query start with rnum > 999999 and < then 200000 `.  I think it will fix the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution that I was looking for given by @hkandapal

If the limit is 1 million, then you can write 10 SQL's and export to a csv.

```
set linesize 2
set numwidth 5enter code here 
spool File1.csv 
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT t.*, rownum rnum FROM table t order by primary_key ) WHERE rnum>= 1 
 and rnum < 1000000 -- For the 2nd query start with rnum > 999999 and < then 200000 
spool off
```

Comment: This will not generate CSV: it will output a fixed-width columns separated by pipes by default, which will be hard to read when some column has newlines/pipes