# Export 1.4 billion rows from single oracle table

Tags: oracle12c

I have a table with about 2.3 billion rows where I need to export about 1.4 billion of these rows to CSV.

Info:

- I have the max pk to retreive.
- PK is indexed.

What would be the best way of doing this?

I have tried the following:

- Using Toad to export whole table: Crashed after about 1.5 billion rows where fetched.
- Using C# with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core to select up to 250 000 rows at the time and write to csv using CsvHelper. The times were not to impressive. About 230s per select...

Statement used with C#:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE pk_table > :lastMaxPk ORDER BY pk_table ASC FETCH FIRST :pageSize ROWS ONLY;`

- Using Sqlplus to write directly to a csv:

```
set linesize 9999
set trimspool on
set heading off
set pagesize 50000
set wrap off
set newpage 0
set arraysize 5000
set term off
set feed off
set echo off
set markup csv
spool out.csv
SELECT * FROM table WHERE pk_table < max_pk ORDER BY pk_table ASC;
spool off
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to export an Oracle Table Chunk-wise to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70133987/how-to-export-an-oracle-table-chunk-wise-to-csv)

Comment: This solution will include the same time issues.

Comment: If you can, depending on your requirements, 1) don't use `order by` as it will *significantly* increase the query time and 2) export to a file on the DB server rather than a network client, as network latency will also be significant.

Comment: I presume that most of the time is taken by *printing* in any of those cases, so it's hard to improve this except improvement of write IO (write locally, use faster device etc). Also do not use `order by` if you do not need specific order. The above query will not use any index access because you ask to fetch more than a half of a table with all the row contents - for DBMS it would be better to leave off index access as it is pointless